# 3D line multiple colors

Tags: excel, matlab

I need help with Matlab.
I have an Excel sheet with three columns: `X`, `Y` and `Z`. I have used plot3 function to make one 3D curve.
But I need to vary it in colors.

What function/functions do I need to make `X`, `Y` and `Z` in different 3 colors(each column one color)? 
Could you please send me link, where I can find out the way, or just write the function/functions needed for it?

Here is the code:

```
VCG=xlsread('VCGsheet.xls');
figure(1)
plot3(VCG(:,1),VCG(:,2),VCG(:,3));
grid on
```

I know that plot3 isn't suitable for it.

Comment: How would you expect X Y and Z to be different colors since for each point in your plot, you need all three components?

Comment: Yes, I need all 3 components. If I plot all 3 components X, Y and Z, then I have the vectorcardiographic curve, and this is what I need. I need a VCG curve to varied in 2 colors, or 3 colors. And I don't need to use plot function, any funciton, but I have to load the data from the excel sheet.


This is my code with plot3 function:
VCG=xlsread('VCGsheet.xls');
figure(1)
plot3(VCG(:,1),VCG(:,2),VCG(:,3));
grid on


And I know plot3 function is not suitable for it. 
I need any function/functions or link where I can find how to achieve it.

Comment: Please edit your question with your code, don't paste it into a comment. Also, what determines the color?

Comment: I want each columnd in a different color.
I want the bounderies of each column to be determined by it's length.
What I mean is that for example X column will be red, Y column will be blue and Z column will be orange.
And I know plot3 is not suitable for it.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Yea it still doesn't make sense. Re-read my first comment to see why this isn't  possible.

Comment: Or is there any possibility to make a 3D curve of the 3 columns, not using the plot function and the color would be based on the speed of the curve?


Or is there any way, that the curve would have only two colors, each color for 1 millsecond? 
Example: 0 - 1 milliseond: red       
1 - 2 millisecond: blue     
2 - 3 millisecond: red        
1 - 2 millisecond: blue    and it continues all the way.

Comment: Here is first example what I mena: https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1186%2F1475-925X-11-16/MediaObjects/12938_2011_549_MOESM6_ESM.jpeg

And here is a second example: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/58241/versions/2/screenshot.jpg

Comment: A little progress:
patch(VKG(:,1),VKG(:,2),VKG(:,3),'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','interp');
grid on


Now I need to do it in 3D, and control the colors as I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a native command that draws line with varying color.

I will also assume that VCG vector is a vector of RGB values, so one color per row.

```
RGB = VCG(:,1:3);
```

If you want, you can replace it (`VCG(:,1:3)`) with any other vector of color derived from your data. Here is an example if you have a single value that can be calculated for each of your points, in the vector `T` for example, and that you want to show as a color.

```
map = jet(256);
RGB = map(round((T(:)-min(T(:)))/(max(T(:)) - min(T(:)))*255)+1,:);
```

For the plot, I propose two different ways:

- you can make use of the `scatter3` function

It will print points, but no lines connecting the points. The color vector is set with `VCG(:,1:3)`

```
colormap('jet')
scatter3(VCG(:,1), VCG(:,2), VCG(:,3), 70, RGB, 'filled');
```

- You can make a direct use of `line` in a for loop.

It is a bit slower, but it is generally ok for graphs.

```
for i=2:size(VCG,1)
   line(VCG(i-1:i,1), VCG(i-1:i,2), VCG(i-1:i,3), 'color', RGB(i-1,:));
end
```

If you want both, just use the `hold` function

I hope I understood what you needed !

Comment: The first one works perfectly, the second one: Error using line
While setting the 'Color' property of Line:
Color value contains NaN, or element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0

BUT THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!

Comment: Now I am going to figure out how only three colors can be used.
Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: May I just ask, what does the 'filled' thing mean in the first case?

Comment: @Franta it should work. You may have NaN (missing values or so) in your dataset. Check it with sum(isnan(VCG(:)))>0 and you can remove them by using `VCG = VCG(any(isnan(VCG),2),:); otherwise, check the way you generate the RGB matrix.

Comment: @Franta, you can see in the documentation. `filled` gives you filled circles insted of just circle.

Comment: @Franta, I can't figure out what you mean by "how only three colors can be used". Do you mean draw only 3 different colors on the graph ?

Comment: Yep, that's is what I mean. Only 3 different colors in one VCG curve.

Comment: figure(1)
colormap([1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1])
scatter3(VKG(:,1),VKG(:,2),VKG(:,3), 50, VKG(:,3),'filled');
hold on
plot3(X,Y,Z)
I just put it together yet.

Comment: Now I have to figure out how to make a proper line.